# Jquery chose plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to understand how chosen works. Focus stays with the input box, but, the keydown/keypress events (DOWN arrow and UP arrow) are delegated to selected box. How is this made possible? Any links and other material to achieve this technique?

Comment: Not too sure why it was closed. However, I did find the reply very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding chosen is that it replicates the select box with entirely separate DOM elements (most specifically a `<ul>` with `<li>` elements) and then works with these.

You can look at the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/). It's written in CoffeeScript, and then uses cakebuild to make the JavaScript, which creates a few oddities that can confuse you a bit :)